# Git Bash and Fabric local() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, fabric, git-bash

Trying to use `Fabric3` locally but having an issue with Git Bash:

```
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'mkdir -p C:\Users\me\path\to\folder\static'
```

The Windows-style path seems to be what's throwing Git Bash off (if I try to run the command as-is normally, it actually creates folders called `-p` and `C:\Users\me\path\to\folder\static`.

This is my code:

```
site_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
local('mkdir -p {0}'.format(
    os.path.join(site_folder, 'static')
))
```

If I print the formatted string:

```
mkdir -p C:\Users\me\path\to\folder\static
```

I tried using `posixpath` but it ends up with a relative path

```
site_folder = posixpath.dirname(posixpath.dirname(__file__))
print('mkdir -p {0}'.format(
    posixpath.join(site_folder, 'static')
))

# output:
# mkdir -p static
```

And `posixpath.abspath` still gives the Windows-style path:

```
local("mkdir -p {0}".format(
    posixpath.abspath((posixpath.join(site_folder, "static")))
))

# Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'mkdir -p C:\Users\user\path\to\folder/static'
```

Comment: If `mkdir -p` creates a directory named "-p", then the shell is probably cmd. Its built-in `mkdir` command implicitly works like bash's `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Thanks for that @eryksun I tried `local(..., shell="/bin/bash.exe")` and got `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified`